# Is there an equivalent sql check to python's concept of truthy / falsy / bool?

Tags: mysql, orm

I'm trying to find the usage of particular columns in a **mysql** database connected to python. Python counts the following to be 'falsy':

- Empty lists: []
- Empty tuples: ()
- Empty dictionaries: {}
- Empty strings ""
- Integer: 0
- Float: 0.0
- None
- False

I realise this is somewhat ORM dependent (e.g. empty datatypes are stored as NULL rather than a string) but is the below somewhat equivalent, is there a better way and is there anything obvious I'm missing? Maybe 0.0? The idea being to calculate a row_count and subtract this result. I tried `NOT IN` for truthy but didn't seem to get a consistent result.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tabBatch` WHERE naming_series IN ('', 0, NULL);
```

Comment: The value cannot be tested for NULL by this way. Either use separate testing: `WHERE naming_series IN ('', 0) OR naming_series IS NULL;` or convert NULL to another value to be tested: `WHERE COALESCE(naming_series, 0) IN ('', 0)`. PS. The latter variant is slower...

Comment: Thanks @Akina, in the end I used below.

Comment: truthy/falsy in a database: I hope not. Almost all RDBMSs have strong typing. `''` is not `false`, it's just an empty string

Comment: @Charlieface empty is not false but it is falsy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found this did what I needed as I needed to use it multiple times in queries and it had to cope with various field types (you can't CAST down from CHAR to INT, only up it seems).

The COALESCE is for tables where there are no rows, SUM returns NULL in this case. This turned out to be useful because in another application I wanted to distinguish between zero rows (SUM = NULL) and rows where all were empty (SUM = 0).

```python
sql_truthy = """
  COALESCE(SUM(
    CASE WHEN `{field}` IS NULL THEN 0
         WHEN CAST(`{field}` AS CHAR) IN ('0', '0.0', '') THEN 0
         ELSE 1
    END
  ), 0) AS used"""
```

The advantage to using this as a column field rather than a WHERE clause is it could be used multiple times in the same query for multiple fields. The WHERE clause needs a query for each field.

Bonus: I used a `COUNT(*) as total` to find the total rows in the same query.

Comment: `SELECT 0+'a', 0+'7x';` --> 0, 7 -- That is, it will extract a number at the beginning of a string and use that.

Comment: For your example, it may be faster to use `EXISTS` than `SUM`: `SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 WHERE ... )`

Comment: You could use `COUNT(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 END)` and that will not give you `NULL` only a number so you don't need `COALESCE`

Comment: @Charlieface presumably I'd have to set values to NULL though as COUNT will account for 0's

Comment: `CASE` with no `ELSE` defaults to `ELSE NULL` anyway, so you only need to do something like `COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST({field} AS CHAR) NOT IN ('0', '0.0', '') THEN 1 END)` and all other cases become `NULL`, and because `COUNT` only counts non-null values, you end up with the same result as your `COALESCE(SUM(`

Comment: @Charlieface No you get the inverse: falsy. And I'd still need the CASE WHEN IS NULL. I'd then have to calculate (total - falsy), but I get your point that it eliminates the COALESCE.

Answer (score 1):

- MySQL returns 3 types of "true/false":  0 (false), 1 (true), NULL.
- In *most* situations where `NULL` is involved, the result will be `NULL`.
- You can test for `NULL` only with these:  `IS NULL`, `IS NOT NULL`, `<=>`.  (OK, I may have forgotten something.)  See also, `COALESCE()`.
- When a column is declared `NOT NULL`, it cannot store a `NULL`; attempts to do so may store 0 / 0.0 / ''.
- Try to avoid the inefficient `WHERE x IS NULL OR x = 0`; pick one or the other for your 'exception' case.
- There are many possible uses for `NULL`; let's discuss your particular business logic.  This general discussion may not be sufficient.
- If a subquery might return no rows, consider whether `EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM .. WHERE ...)` would work faster.  It always returns 0 or 1.
- `NULL` values are ignored by certain aggregates (see `GROUP BY`).

Run these to see some examples:

```
SELECT NULL IN (1, 2);  --> NULL
SELECT 1 IN (1, NULL);  --> 1
SELECT 1 IN (2, NULL);  --> NULL
SELECT NULL IN (1, NULL); --> NULL
```

Think of it this way, `NULL` represents any possible value; it does not know which one.

Comment: Add `SELECT NULL IN (1, NULL);  -- > NULL`